# How to create custom commands in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command

In Emacs, I can create functions in Lisp language and place them in `.emacs` file. Those function will become commands that can be called from the editor or bound to keys just like any other built-in command.

Is there a way to do that in VSCode?

Note: The custom commands need to be able to call other commands. Simply using a batch file and running it as a task will not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few marketplace extensions may be of interest:

- [**Script Commands** by *Marcel J. Kloubert*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkloubert.vs-script-commands)
- [**multi-command** by *ryuta46*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

However in general, you'll need to [write an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) to do anything complex.

There's also [a VS Code issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4490) tracking support for built-in macros

Answer (score 3):

There's [Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ego-digital.vscode-powertools) by [e.GO:digital](https://e-go-digital.com/). It has support for custom commands and event triggers (ie. on file changed), among other things.