# Possible to create a VS Code Keyboard Shortcut for Comment at End of Line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, vscode-snippets

Is there a way to create a keyboard shortcut in VS Code where I can begin a comment ( creating opening and closing comment brackets if applicable ) at the end of a line of code? - like so:

```
<h3>Example</h3>
<div class="keyboard-shortcut"></div> <!-- comment here -->
<h3>Example</h3>
```

I know to use Ctrl+/ or Ctrl+K Ctrl+C ( I am using Ubuntu Linux ) - in order to comment out the entire line or selection like this:

```
<h3>Example</h3>
<!--  <div class="keyboard-shortcut"></div> -->
<h3>End of Line</h3>
```

An HTML example is used here but I would like to use a keyboard shortcut to begin a comment at the end of a line in any common programming language - as if I were beginning a comment on a blank line.

I know how to create custom key mappings. I am wondering if the above described operation is possible - or if an extension might exist for accomplishing this task.

Or would one have to create their own extension to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom commands in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49178842/how-to-create-custom-commands-in-vscode)

Comment: @Addison That does not help much, no. I am wondering if this functionality exists in VS Code. Has anyone else found a way to accomplish this - without simply typing the comment syntax at the end of a line of code?

Comment: It could probably be done, but you would have to either make a snippet or a macro (would you always be at the end of the line when you trigger the end-of-line comment functionality or from anywhere on that line - if anywhere you will certainly need a macro as @Addison suggested).  Do you want to see a macro? You seemed to have rejected that approach.

Comment: @Mark I was thinking that the cursor would be at the end of the line before I trigger this. The snippet idea sounds like a good one. If I understand this approach correctly I would need to create my snippet for each language for which I wanted this functionality. But being able to do it from anywhere in the line sounds even better. I would like to see a macro, yes. I felt the answer previous to yours did not answer my specific question. Mine is not a duplicate question. I was asking if VS Code had functionality to accomplish this task. It appears not. I would like to learn more about macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this as a simple snippet, your cursor would have to be at the end of the line already:

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",                                // choose your own keybinding

    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",

    // delete next line if using block comment form for all filetypes
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|scss|css)/"

    "args": {
      "snippet": "  $BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 $BLOCK_COMMENT_END"

      // "snippet": "  $LINE_COMMENT $1 "
  }
},
```

There are two versions of snippet variables available for this: `$BLOCK_COMMENT_START` and  `$LINE_COMMENT`.  You may prefer one over the other but `$BLOCK_COMMENT_START` appears to work for more languages, like html where the `$LINE_COMMENT` version doesn't do anything when triggered at the end of a line.

You could make two versions of this snippet: one with `$BLOCK_COMMENT_START` languages and for the `$LINE_COMMENT` languages just by modifying the `resourceExtname` clause as shown above.

---

Alternatively, to get more functionality you could make a macro.  You could then trigger an EOL comment from anywhere in the line.  Using [the multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command), put this in your settings.json:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.insertBlockCommentEOL",
    "sequence": [
      "cursorLineEnd",
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "  $BLOCK_COMMENT_START $1 $BLOCK_COMMENT_END"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Then some keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",
  "command": "multiCommand.insertBlockCommentEOL",

  // remove below if using block comment form for all languages
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|scss|css)/"
}
```

Same comment as above about the form of the comments: block or line comments.  You could make a copy of the macro named slightly different and then another keybinding (using the same trigger) but with a different `when` clause for different languages that would trigger the other macro that uses line comments.

I'll show the other forms here (but you may not need them if using the block comment form is okay for you, in which case just remove the `&& resourceExtname =~ /\\.(html|scss|css)/` from the end of the first `when` clause above).

```
{
  "command": "multiCommand.insertLineCommentEOL",
  "sequence": [
    "cursorLineEnd",
    {
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": "  $LINE_COMMENT $1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "key": "alt+-",
  "command": "multiCommand.insertLineCommentEOL",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js|ts|php)/"
}
```

If all this isn't clear, let me know.  Here is a demo on different files using both comment forms (as demonstrated, if you trigger the macro with a mulit-line selection, the comment will be aded to the end of the line with the cursor only - although it could probably be modified to put a comment at the end of all lines selected):

[image: demo of EOL comments]

Comment: Answer accepted. I just now learned how to do that, as well. ( This was my first question on Stack Overflow ). I am still new to programming. I can see how this approach can make VS Code more personalized -  for this task and other tasks. You've given me a lot of stuff to try out here. I appreciate your generosity on this. You've gone beyond what I was hoping for. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to have helped.