# Convert a CMD command to a VS Code command

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmd

I want to convert this cmd command to a vs code command. (I need it for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353745/build-and-run-c-in-vs-code))

```
start ${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe
```

I tried [command-runner extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=edonet.vscode-command-runner) but it's not making a vs code command for me.
Can someone give me a solution? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202178/447901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`start ${fileDirname}\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe` is a shell command, so you could run it with:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.build_and_run",
    "sequence": [
        "workbench.action.tasks.build",
        // "\"start ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"",
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": {
            "text": "start ${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
           }
        }
     ]
  }
]
```

I don't know that that sequence is necessarily guaranteed to be sequential though.  You'll have to test that - you could always add the `interval` option if necessary.  There are also shell runner extensions that could be plugged into `multi-command`.  `multi-command` can't just run shell commands by itself without `sendSequence` or through another shell runner extension's commands.